# Java FX Packager Error IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to build a project of mine as an application. I have set up a 'JavaFX Application' artifact which has been set up correctly as it works on my friends computer.

When I run the program and it attempts to complete the build, I get the following error:

```
Error:Java FX Packager: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/AntMain
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:278)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.AntMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
ant.home: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant
Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jai.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
Launcher JAR: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar
Launcher Directory: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib
```

Im really unsure how to go about fixing this. Anyone know what it could be?

Comment: Do you get this exception when you are trying to run configuration from IDE? What steps in *Before launch* section do you have in Run Configuration? Do you have *Ant* plugin enabled in IDE? Try also if it helps to re-download and re-install from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: @Andrey Ant Plugin is enabled and I have tried re-downloading the IDE but I still have no success